# Actualizar un array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Tengo este  este array, cuando lo recorro y si encuentro un id pasado por parametro, este deberia actualizarme el otro campo de mi arreglo.
pero cuando imprimo, el arreglo final, este no se ha actualizado.
que puedo estar haciendo mal?

De paso si alguien sabe, como asi como actualizo puedo eliminar, se lo agradezco, muchas gracias.

```
$valor_almacenado = array(array());  //[{"cant":"10","id":"54"},{"cant":11,"id":55}]
$buscar= 55;

        foreach ($valor_almacenado as $items => $items_value) {
            if ($items_value['id'] === $buscar ){
                $items_value['cant'] = 45;
                break;
            } 
        }
        
        dd($valor_almacenado);
```

Cuando hago el dd me imprime lo mismo que el original, sin cambios

```
[{"cant":"10","id":"54"},{"cant":11,"id":55}]
```

Estoy usando laravel, que es php.

Comment: Cuando usas la sintaxis con clave de `foreach`, puedes asignar a `$valor_almacenado[$items]` y borrar con `unset($valor_almacenado[$items])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres modificar el array tienes que [**asignarlo por referencia**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php), como explica el Manual de PHP:

> Para poder modificar directamente los elementos del array dentro de
> bucle, se ha de anteponer `&` a `$valor`. En este caso el valor será
> asignado por [referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.php).

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$valor_almacenado = array(array("cant"=>10, "id"=>54), array("cant"=>11, "id"=>55));  //[{"cant":"10","id":"54"},{"cant":11,"id":55}]
#Antes
var_dump($valor_almacenado);
$buscar= 55;

        foreach ($valor_almacenado as $items => &$items_value) {
            if ($items_value['id'] === $buscar ){
                $items_value['cant'] = 45;
                break;
            } 
        }

#Después        
var_dump($valor_almacenado);
```

Este es el `var_dump` de antes, con los datos originales:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cant"]=>
    int(10)
    ["id"]=>
    int(54)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cant"]=>
    int(11)
    ["id"]=>
    int(55)
  }
}
```

Y este es el `var_dump` de después de haber pasado por el `foreach`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cant"]=>
    int(10)
    ["id"]=>
    int(54)
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(2) {
    ["cant"]=>
    int(45)
    ["id"]=>
    int(55)
  }
}
```

La clave de todo está aquí:

```
    foreach ($valor_almacenado as $items => &$items_value) {
```

Al poner `&`  delante de `$items_value` estamos indicando que se pasa **por referencia** y que cualquier cambio que ocurra con `$items_value` quede reflejado en dicho objeto.

Comment: @Sal tienes toda la razón, gracias por tu comentario, en base al cual he actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: En sentido estricto no es *paso por referencia*, ya que `foreach` no es una función, sino una construcción de lenguaje, en la cual se *"pasa"* el arreglo mas no el valor (del elemento del arreglo). Es más preciso llamarle *Referenciar el valor*, o *Asignación por referencia* del valor, considerando que en `as $clave => $valor` `$clave` y `$valor` son declaraciones de variables.

Answer (score 0):

el array son datos anillados

si quiero acceder a un dato especifico se hace de la siguiente manera

$valor_almacenado[2]['cant'];

con el foreach se hace de las siguiente manera

```
var_dump($valor_almacenado);
foreach ($valor_almacenado as $items => $items_value) {
    if ($valor_almacenado[$items]['id'] == $buscar ){
        $valor_almacenado[$items]['cant'] = 45;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($valor_almacenado);
```

el uso de if === hace que la consulta sea muy especifica como si son datos numéricos o String es mejor utilizar if ==

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo, sabrias ¿como puedo eliminar un elemento de este array? buscando tambien por id.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, si lo que quieres es escribir sobre tu arreglo es mejor que utilices el ciclo for, en vez del foreach, ya que, este último hace una referencia al valor por cada iteración y no estás trabajando directamente sobre el valor original.

Código:

```
$valor_almacenado = array(array("cant"=>10, "id"=>54), array("cant"=>11, "id"=>55));  //[{"cant":"10","id":"54"},{"cant":11,"id":55}]
$buscar= 55;

for($i=0; $i < count($valor_almacenado); $i++) {
    if($valor_almacenado[$i]["id"] == $buscar) {
        $valor_almacenado[$i]["cant"] = 45;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($valor_almacenado);
```

Salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cant] => 10
            [id] => 54
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cant] => 45
            [id] => 55
        )

)
```